# React.js Cant replace image source when image throws a 500 error

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component which basically grabs an image and outputs it. However my issue is that I cant replace the image source when the image throws a 500. My page will return the image path (/images/icons/image.png) however that image itself does not exist, so it throws a 500 on me. This is fine, the issue is it wont trigger the onerror in the image so I cant replace the broken image with a fallback image. I've tried changing state, as well as an inline onerror function. None of those will work for me. WOuld anyone has a fix for this issue. This is what my component looks like:

```
const VerifiedLogo = ({ src, alt, isVerified }) => (
    <div className={styles.logo}>
        <img src={src ? src : '/images/icons/tournament-logo-placeholder.png'} alt={alt} onError="this.src='/images/icons/tournament-logo-placeholder.png'" />
        <VerifiedBadge isVisible={isVerified} />
    </div>
);

export default VerifiedLogo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onError` expects a **function**, in the `constructor`:

```
    this.state = {
      logoOk: false
    }
```

in the `render`:

```
<img src={this.state.logoOk ? src : altLink} onError={()=>this.setState({logoOk: false})}/>
```